# Problem changing from for loop and if condition to list comprehension and using ortools

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm writing a python program making use of ortools to solve a problem. I'm trying to change *for* loops as much as possible using list comprehension. Almost all gone well, but there is one I can't get changed

The original one works well:

```
L_Filas = [i for i in range(9)]  
C_Columnas = [i for i in range(9)] 
# tablaOrigD is a nested dictionary, imported from an Excel sheet

modname = 'Sudoku'

solver = pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING
#solver = pywraplp.Solver.GUROBI_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING

s: Solver = pywraplp.Solver(modname, solver)

    #############
    # Variables #
    #############


x = [[[s.IntVar(0, 1, 'X_%s_%s_%s' % (i, j, k)) for k in nValores] for j in nColumnas] for i in nFilas]

nula = s.NumVar(0, 10, 'Nula')

    #################
    # RESTRICCIONES #
    #################

for f in L_Filas:
     for c in L_Columnas:
          if tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1] :
                s.Add(x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1] - 1] == 1)
      #[s.Add((x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1] - 1] for c in L_Columnas if tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1])==1)]
```

One step at a time, first I'm trying to change the most internal loop (c var):

```
for f in L_filas:
        [s.Add((x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f + 1][c + 1] - 1] for c in L_Columnas if tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1])==1)]
```

This doesn't work. There is no syntax nor other errors. Program ends giving an incorrect result.

Where is my error?

Comment: I don't think a list comprehension is the right tool here. Your new code is producing a list just to throw it away. Why? Just use a for loop.

Comment: It looks like you're calling a method on `s` inside the comprehension, which is not typically how comprehensions should be used. You need to add more code (like how you define `s`) to provide a [mre].

Comment: @Craig and Adam: many thanks. I'm sorry to be so short in my original question. I've edited it, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Craig there is currently no chance to reproduce your program so I have to make some assumptions. I am assuming that the `s.Add()` in your first code sample actually uses one `\t` more than shown in your snippet. I would argue that at least the parantheses within the list comprehension are not set properly.
So my comprehensed list is referring to an original code looking like:

```
for f in L_Filas:
    for c in L_Columnas:
        if tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1]:
            s.Add(x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1] - 1] == 1)
```

Could be simplified to:

```
[s.Add(x[f][c][tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1] - 1] == 1) for f in L_Filas for c in L_Columnas if tablaOrigD[f+1][c+1]]
```

If this is not helpful, please provide further information on your problem and `s.Add()` as well as whether you're aware that you're passing an expression, a `boolean`, to `s.Add()`.

Comment: Thankyou Simon. I've tried you advice but it throws:
`list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Comment: Okay, I modified it slightly - had one issue in the first version. Please note that my list comprehension has to be placed outside of the `for f in L_Filas` loop. Does it work now? I've tried to run some tests but I can just guess how `nValores, nColumnas, nFilas` and `tablaOrigD` actually look like. If it still does not work, could you provide one or two dummy values for `x` and `tablaOrigD`?

Comment: Fantastic!. It works fine.
Many thanks. I'm going to study your code deeply, it will give me a better understanding of list comprehension.